# Mark first ocurrence in a dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have the following dataframe

[image: Orignal dataframe]

Now, I want to count the first time that an animal has a certain number of legs (the first animal with 2 legs is falcon, spider is the first one with 8 legs, fish with no legs and horse with 4) in order to obtain something like this

[image: Desired dataframe]

I guess it has something to do with drop_dplicates(keep="first") (in order to get the desired ones), however from there I don't know how to follow in a optimal way

This is the DDL for the dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'animal': ['falcon','eagle', 'dog', 'spider', 'fish','horse','cow','ant','worm'],
'num_legs': [2,2,4,8,0,4,4,8,0],
'num_wings': [2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]})
```

Comment: Please share a sample of the dataframe, not an image (we can't reproduce it otherwise)

Comment: There's a screen capture of both, the original and the desired

Comment: A sample, just copy/paste the dataframe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) with [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['Desired'] = np.where(df['num_legs'].duplicated(), '', 'X')
print (df)

   animal  num_legs  num_wings Desired
0  falcon         2          2       X
1   eagle         2          2        
2     dog         4          0       X
3  spider         8          0       X
4    fish         0          0       X
5   horse         4          0        
6     cow         4          0        
7     ant         8          0        
8    worm         0          0
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you can use `duplicated`:

```
df.loc[~df.num_legs.duplicated(), 'Desired'] = 'X'

print(df.fillna(''))

  animal  num_legs  num_wings Desired
0  falcon         2          2       X
1   eagle         2          2        
2     dog         4          0       X
3  spider         8          0       X
4    fish         0          0       X
5   horse         4          0        
6     cow         4          0        
7     ant         8          0        
8    worm         0          0
```